# Jquery .load not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, load

How to insert a div from one page into a div on current.

My method using .Load below was working but has stopped and I am unsure why.

```
$("#button").on('click', function() {
    $("#div").load('../url.aspx #div2');
});
```

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong load.  I don't believe THAT load is deprecated, the other is.

Comment: Thanks, please then can you assist why my code as added above works fine in jquery 1.8 but fails when I switch to 1.9.1

Comment: Perhaps the content returned from url.aspx no longer has a div with the id 'div2' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you are using isn't deprecated - you are thinking of the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event.

In regard to your code - it should be working. You mentioned that it worked sometimes when trying with `on()` but not with it's shortcut `click()` - maybe you can try refreshing your browser cache or look at other parts of your code that you feel may be causing this (maybe what you're trying to load)?

Comment: I believe this is not the `load` to which the question is referring.

Comment: You misunderstood question :)

Comment: @user125697 How does this make any difference at all?  @DreamTek accepted the answer, implying that it fixed his problem, but I fail to see how that's possible as `click` simply calls `on`.

Comment: Apologies @user125697 for delayed response. It appears you are right it did not fix my issue as it has now reoccurred. I assume it temporarily fixed due to some kind of caching. So the question remains. I really cannot work out what I have changed to break it.

Comment: I have had a bonfire with my entire cache it definitely gone. So the code above is correct?

Comment: @DreamTeK Yeah the code above is fine, does it still work sometimes? what are you actually loading?

Comment: A gridview from another page. It does not work at all now although I have been cleaning up my js.

Comment: @DreamTeK You've console.log'd inside of the click event to check whether it's the click itself or the load()? if it's the load, maybe an issue with the url or the gridview

Comment: Thank you for helping. You are correct it was another part of my javascript further up causing everything after to fail. Much appreciated.

Comment: @DreamTeK No problems man, glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

The event [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is deprecated as of 1.8.

The [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which you are asking about is not deprecated and can still be used without worry.

If for some reason you still want to replace `load`, you can use any number of other methods:  `ajax`, `get`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, please then can you assist why my code as added above works fine in jquery 1.8 but fails when I switch to 1.9.1

Comment: Well, for one, even if it were deprecated, that would not break code.  Deprecated simply means it is not suggested to use it as it will be removed in the future.  Deprecated methods still work.  2nd, I would need more information to even begin to answer why that stopped working.  It looks fine to me.  Do you get any errors?